# select common element from various tables where all values are not null

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables, A,B, and C. Each table has a common column, ID, plus other data.
I want to have all IDs that are in every table and where all data are not null.
What is the most efficent way to do it?
In my real case I have more than 5 tables.

Ex:

```
Table A
| ID | A_1 | A_2 | A_3 | A_4 | A_5 | A_6 |

Table B
| ID | B_1 | B_2 | B_3 | B_4 |

Table C
| ID | C_1 | C_2 | C_3 | C_4 | C_5 | C_6 | C_7 | C_8 |
```

This query will take all the ID in common among the three tables.

```
SELECT  distinct ID FROM A
where  
   exists(select 1 from B where A.ID = B.ID )
   AND exists(select 1 from C where A.ID = C.ID );
```

This query will select ID in which all columns are non null :

```
SELECT ID 
FROM A
WHERE A_1 IS NOT NULL AND A_2 IS NOT NULL AND A_3 IS NOT NULL AND A_4 IS NOT NULL AND A_5 IS NOT NULL;
```

(I hope there is a better query for this.)

Than I should have the same query for all tables.
And then join all together.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: This looks like poor design

Comment: You mean, the design of the tables? The tables contains data inserted manually by people and exported by a system not under our control. Our goal with these queries it to let people know which data are inserted completely. People must be able to insert data in different phases, so we cannot force them to complete each row before submitting. And different people insert data in different tables.

Comment: well, if you really can't change the design, I'd start with about 100 unions.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID AND B.value IS NOT NULL
INNER JOIN C ON A.ID = C.ID AND C.value IS NOT NULL
INNER JOIN D ON A.ID = D.ID AND D.value IS NOT NULL
INNER JOIN E ON A.ID = E.ID AND E.value IS NOT NULL
WHERE A.value IS NOT NULL
;
```

The downside of it is that if there are one or more one-to-many relationships the intermediate results could proverbially explode. A better solution MIGHT be more similar to your first example; but instead of using correlated EXISTS subqueries....

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID 
FROM A
WHERE A.Value IS NOT NULL 
   AND A.ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM B WHERE Value IS NOT NULL)
   AND A.ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM C WHERE Value IS NOT NULL)
   AND A.ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM D WHERE Value IS NOT NULL)
   AND A.ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM E WHERE Value IS NOT NULL)
   ...etc
```

The downside of this is you won't get any benefit from indexes on ID. If the "explosion" issue I mentioned isn't a concern, and ID is indexed on all or most of the tables, my first suggestion would likely be faster and more efficient.

Edit: Oh, I overlooked you meant multiple values in each table NOT NULL, but the same concept should apply, you'll just have to replace all the `Value IS NOT NULL` conditions with `AND`ed IS NOT NULL conditions on the appropriate columns.